# Spring project that imports another spring project

Tags: java, spring

I have two spring projects. Both are currently portlets.

I would like to take one and convert it to a jar and add it as a dependancy (using maven) to the other then call the code)

Any advice on the steps would be great.

I have tried and although everything (inc context)  gets packaged in my jar , it appears when calling classes from within the portlet consuming the jar the application context is not loaded/working

```
Current jar structure 
application-context.xml
META-INF/
<package>/classes
```

EDIT_*_*
Re errors: Cannot Find Bean Definition for class x

Comment: did you mean when you try to load application context from jar its not working ? if so error message ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this but it highly depends on what you are trying to do. You can include the context in your web.xml...

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, classpath:childContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Another option is to import the child context directly from your application context.

```
<import  resource="classpath:childContext.xml/>
```

I'm not an overly big fan of this since these contexts get merged which can be a nightmare for bean names; however, they do work.

It's usually better that your JAR exposes some sort of factory or static constructor that reads it's own Spring config XML and then simply exposes what you want to use as a service. This might not be the best solution for your particular problem but it is something to consider.

Comment: Thanks I will try that.(factory/static method option) So I would use applicationContext object in that method -- Any tips on the file structure my jar shoudl take? -- I will edit the above to show current structure

Comment: Worked like a charm !!! Creating a static method, loading the context and getting the service bean from that was spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the answers provided by Andrew will work. But as he notes it is usually not a good idea to merge together beans from different projects this way. 
You might want to step back a little and consider these questions:

1. Why are the two different projects in the first place? Do you want to reuse the second project across several parent projects?
2. What components/services exposed by the child context need to be consumed directly by the parent context.

Re-thinking these dependencies might lead to a more elegant and maintainable solution.

Comment: Thanks very much, answer to 1. is yes.  Answer to 2 is it is code that exposes a service which lookups information in dbs to create a object used by all the other consumers (I don't want to create this in every project)